# How to generate an image of the entire contents of TScrollBox?

Tags: delphi

I want to generate an image of the entire contents of TScrollBox. Like a screenshot. Even if all the content is not within the visible screen area.

Comment: The non-visible area of the scrollbox is not painted because of Windows clipping, so there is no way to get a screenshot of this.

Answer (score 4):

Each TControl descendant has a `Perform` method you can use to make it perform as if it's processing a windows message, so this should work:

```
var
  b:TBitmap;
begin
  b:=Image1.Picture.Bitmap;//or b:=TBitmap.Create;
  b.Width:=ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Range;
  b.Height:=ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Range;
  SetWindowOrgEx(b.Canvas.Handle,-ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position,-ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position,nil);
  ScrollBox1.Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND,b.Canvas.Handle,0);
  ScrollBox1.Perform(WM_PAINT,b.Canvas.Handle,0);
```

Comment: If I have a quick look at `TWinControl.PaintTo` I see `WM_ERASEBKGND` which I'll add here, but also code to set up clipping, which would prevent painting of children controls that are scrolled out of view.

Comment: You're quite close, but the windowed controls are not painted to the target. Maybe you need to iterate all the children based on window controls and perform those two messages with respect to their Z order.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `TWinControl.PaintControls` does?

Comment: Right now I've tried to call `PaintControls` and it gives the same result as your code, without windowed controls.

Comment: Not only controls, when I try this code, it doesn't even paint the background outside of the client rectangle. Start with a *red* bitmap f.i. to verify.

Comment: Yes, looks like default WM_ERASEBKGND does clipping by itself as well, just fill the bitmap with clBtnFace yourself.

Comment: @Stijn - What if the control is painting a background itself, e.g an image? Besides, you don't need to send a WM_PAINT etc. to a control, if what you'll end up is filling some rectangle yourself.